# Elementary number theory problem for homological algebra

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Hello to everybody: I'd like to know if the following statement is true or not, since if it's false it will help me solving a problem for exact sequences of modules.

$``$Given $(a,b,m) \in \mathbb{Z}^3$ if $[a,m]= [b,m]$ and $a \equiv b (\textrm{mod} \ m)$ then  $a\in \{b,-b\}"$.

Where I denote by $[a,m]$ the least common multiple of $a,m$. I tried to find a counterexample but I didn't succeed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $m = 0$, we have $\lvert a\rvert = [a,m] = [b,m] = \lvert b\rvert$, if the least common multiple is defined to be non-negative, so it's okay. If $m \neq 0$, then we have

$$\frac{\lvert am\rvert}{\gcd(a,m)} = [a,m] = [b,m] = \frac{\lvert bm\rvert}{\gcd(b,m)},$$

and $a \equiv b \pmod{m}$ ensures $\gcd(a,m) = \gcd(b,m)$, hence $\lvert a \rvert = \lvert b\rvert$ follows.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to find another way!

Comment: I have to prove or disprove that if $0 \to N \to M \to Q \to 0$ is exact and $M_1,M_2$ are submodules of $M$ such that $\alpha^{-1}(M_1)=\alpha^{-1}(M_2)$ and $\beta(M_1)=\beta(M_2)$ then $M_1=M_2$, where $\alpha, \beta$ are the arrows of the sequence.
So I tried with the case $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/ m \mathbb{Z}$, which led me here.

Comment: @Lano If there are no further restrictions, $N = Q = \mathbb{Z}$, $M = \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$, $M_1 = \mathbb{Z}\oplus \{0\}$, $M_2 = \{0\}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$, $\alpha(k) = (k,-k),\; \beta(k,m) = k+m$. You have $\alpha^{-1}(M_1) = \alpha^{-1}(M_2) = \{0\}$, and $\beta(M_1) = \beta(M_2) = Q$.

Comment: Thank you for this Mayer-Vietoris flavoured solution!